# Flex box with nowrap not aligned properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I have content inside a `<div>` with nowrap property. I'm using flex box to align the content vertically and horizontally to be center.

Since I'm using nowrap property and fixed width to my `<div>`, my content overflow outside the container both x and y direction. I understand it will happen because of the property used.

My intention is if the content is too long to hold by the container it should be left aligned rather than center aligned and can overflow only in the Y direction.

I want solutions without adding an extra DOM. Is it possible.

```css
div{
  width:330px;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid #a7a7a7;
  text-align:center;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  white-space:nowrap;
  position:relative
}
```

```html
<div>
  Delete some content so that you can see it aligned properly
</div>
```

Also refer the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8bz5eL4/2/) below

Previously this was possible in display:-webkit-box since it has been deprecated i'm trying to find solution in flex. Refer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f8bz5eL4/4/)

Comment: CSS can't detect overflow. You'll need to use Javascript.

Comment: @Paulie_D it worked for me fine when i use display:box property.Since it is deprecated i'm finding for solution in flex. Refer the working fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/f8bz5eL4/3/ It was possible in css before. Add some extra content to check it

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that this is no longer possible...even with flexbox.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar does the box have to be 350px all the time or can it be smaller and then grow up to 350px?

Comment: @pete Container can be resized by the user. So the width varies. It can be of any width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `justify-content` to `flex-start;`:

```css
div{
  width:330px;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid #a7a7a7;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  align-items:center;
  white-space:nowrap;
  position:relative
}
```

```html
<div>
  Delete some content so that you can see it aligned properly
</div>
```

**Update**

As per your comment if you change the box to inline-flex, you can center the div and then set a max width on it so it is centered but then left-aligned when it hits the max width:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  max-width: 330px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 330px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Delete some content so that you can see it aligned properly
</div>
<br>
<div>
  you can see it aligned properly
</div>
```

Comment: @pete I want content inside the div to be centered not the whole div. Also set max-width to some larger no. You can see that content is not aligned center

Comment: It's OK as far as it goes but this will not work for resizable divs...which is anotehr requirement of the OP (albeit mentioned in the comments).

Comment: @Paulie_D i have workaround for that... No worries... U keep ur down voting skills updated.